# android sdk in linux

Tags: android, linux

I downloaded android adt bundle for linux 32bit and created project using command line.
But when i try to run adb it tells cannot execute binary file..Any help?

```
adb devices 
adb : cannot execute binary file
```

I followed the steps by reffering this link http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html
created project like this:

```
android create project \
--target 1 \
--name MyAndroidApp \
--path ./MyAndroidAppProject \
--activity MyAndroidAppActivity \
--package com.example.myandroid
```

Comment: if i run ./adb devices then also it gives the same error

Comment: Do you have permissions (including exec permissions) to run the file?

Comment: chmod +x adb, then run ./adb

Comment: It is working now but its giving as waiting for device from long time

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're running on 32bit linux as well (since you said you downloaded the 32bit ADK). `uname -a` should give you a hint. If that does not resolve it, try `ldd /path/to/adb` and see if there are any errors with missing or wrong versions of libraries.

Comment: yeah thats 32bit linux..And is that ldd?

Comment: Yes, `ldd - print shared library dependecies`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many times but now it works.

In resume, for 32bit OS:

- download platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip (I think the name is correct) from Google search
- copy files inside this zip to your Sdk platform-tools folder
- open Terminal (a program pre-installs in Ubuntu: press Windows button and type " terminal"
- Type "cd /path_to_your_sdk/platform-tools"
- Type "chmod +x adb"
- Type "chmod +x fastboot"
- Then, copy those files to /usr/local/bin by typing always in the terminal you're in :"sudo cp adb /usr/local/bin" "sudo cp fastboot /usr/local/bin"
- Then, type adb and enjoy Android programing.

N.B: To use Android Studio without problem:

- type "sudo -i" and enter your account password
- go to your android-studio bin folder ("cd /your_path_to_android_studio/bin")
- then type ./studio.sh (This N.B process avoid problems of permission in the next)